# Texture not appears?

Tags: unity, textures

I make fat cube "fbx" with blender and export it to unity. this fat cube not allowed texture to appears ! i make a small cube by unity and texture pop-up !
What is wrong ?
[image: fat and small cube]

Comment: Did you UV map the cube before export?

Comment: No. I'm using ready texture. Do i need to make UV for all and any object i make by blender to appears in unity?

Comment: Yep.  There are several steps you need to go through when exporting models into game engines and UV-mapping is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is missing a UV-map and therefore materials cannot be assigned to it.

Unity provides decent [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ArtAssetBestPracticeGuide.html) on what you need to do when importing models from modelling packages.

Comment: This will take long time. is there any thing can help me with this ?

Comment: It doesn't take long.  The more you do it the easier it gets, so I would suggest you try.